# How to hold 4 to 5 MB of json data throughout a user session in spring.

Tags: json, spring, session

I have a third party API and for every result from that API i have to pay some fee. Now if a user hit that API and on the result he want to  apply some filter for some specific data or wanted to do some operation on that data throughout his session then i want to hold the API result for him instead of giving another call to API. API provides json data of 9 to 12 MB on every hit so what should i do for that should i use session to hold that or there is some other things i can use?

**What i have already tried** 
I am using session variable for that, but not so sure what it will do on production.

Comment: Do you require all that JSON response or you can filter it from unnecessary data/fields? If not - you can use a cache provider for it (like Spring @Cacheble with Redis, for example) and set the eviction policy yourself. But this data is coupled to session information - you can store it in the Session, but use Redis for it, not memory. (Redis can store 512 MB Strings)